# Qual a diferença entre URL e URI?

Tags: url, terminologia, uri

O que é URL? O que é URI? São sinônimos? Em geral as pessoas usam quase sempre URL, são a mesma coisa? Tem mais alguma coisa relacionada?

Comment: URI = URL ou URN, ou seja, a URL é uma categoria de URI.
Logo todo URL é uma URI, e o contrário não é verdade, pois, uma URI pode ser uma URN.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

> URI ou **Identificador Uniforme de Recursos** ou *Uniform Resource Identifier* (em inglês) é uma cadeia de caracteres compacta usada para identificar ou denominar um recurso na Internet. O principal propósito desta identificação é permitir a interação com representações do recurso através de uma rede, tipicamente a Rede Mundial, usando protocolos específicos. URIs são identificados em grupos definindo uma sintaxe específica e protocolos associados.

Fonte: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier)

É uma forma generalizada de denominar tanto URLs quanto URNs.

É raro usarmos o termo URN, especialmente em programação.

> Um **Nome Uniforme de Recurso**, URN (do inglês *Uniform Resource Name*) é um tipo de URI que usa o URN Scheme e que tem por objetivo a identificação única do recurso, de forma persistente e independente da sua localização.

Fonte: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Name)

Um exemplo de URN seria `urn:lex:br:federal:lei:2008-06-19;11705`. Esta é uma forma padronizada para referenciar esta lei. O mesmo vale para livros, metadados e outros identificadores únicos.

Este identificador vive dentro de um *namespace*.

O que importa mais para os programadores é o URL já que precisamos identificar além de um nome único, a localização daquele recurso.

> Um URL (de *Uniform Resource Locator*), em português **Localizador-Padrão de Recursos**, é o endereço de um recurso (como um arquivo, uma impressora etc.), disponível em uma rede; seja a Internet, ou mesmo uma rede corporativa como uma intranet.

Um URL completo tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
esquema://domínio:porta/caminho/recurso?querystring#fragmento
```

- esquema, ou protocolo, poderá ser HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, entre outros.
- domínio, ou máquina, designa o servidor que disponibiliza o documento ou recurso designado.
- porta, ou porto, é o ponto lógico no qual pode-se fazer a conexão com o servidor (opcional).
- caminho especifica o local (geralmente num sistema de arquivos) onde se encontra o - recurso dentro do servidor.
- *query string* é um conjunto de parâmetros a ser enviado ao servidor, usado para localizar, filtrar, ou mesmo criar o recurso (opcional).
- identificador de fragmento se refere a uma parte ou posição específica dentro do recurso (opcional).

O esquema diz como conectar, o domínio especifica onde conectar, e o resto especifica o que está sendo pedido.

Exemplo:

```
http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/uri-spec.html
```

o protocolo é o `HTTP`, o servidor é designado por `www.w3.org` e o recurso — neste caso o arquivo `uri-spec.html` — encontra-se em `Addressing/URL/`. A porta, omitida, recai sobre o padrão do protocolo (no caso, `80`) e não há query *string* ou identificador de fragmento.

Fonte: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)

Outro exemplo de URL:

```
mailto:nomedealguem@example.com
```

Você tem o protocolo `mailto:` o identificador `nomedealguem` e onde está localizado `example.com`.

## Informações adicionais

Todo URL é um URI mas o oposto não é verdadeiro.

Podemos dizer que um URN é uma pessoa e um URL é um endereço completo.

Já vi algumas pessoas usarem o nome de uma pessoa como exemplo de URN. Isto está errado. O documento dessa pessoa seria mais apropriado como identificador dessa pessoa. O nome não é único, o documento é, desde que ele seja especificado apropriadamente.

Notou que há uma discrepância na tradução fornecida pela Wikipedia entre URL e URI? Não sei se existe uma fonte formal que indique qual é o correto (você conhece?) mas eu acho que o "Uniforme" deveria ser usado como tradução de todos estes termos. "Padrão" me parece estranho para o caso (<sup>mas vai tentar mudar na pt.wikipedia para ver o que lhe acontece :)</sup>).
[image: URI]

## Confusão

Preste atenção em duas confusões frequentes:

- URL é um localizador e não uma localização.
- Por consequência é masculino e não feminino como as pessoas costumam usar. Então devemos usar **o** URL.

Ninguém vai brigar com você por usar URL, mas este termo é [considerado mais informal](https://www.w3.org/TR/uri-clarification/). Em geral toda vez que você está usando o termo URL na verdade deveria usar URI. Afinal quando você coloca um endereço de um recurso você está colocando a localização de um recurso com um identificador único, usa o URL e o URN, portanto está se referenciando a um URI e [formalmente é recomendado o seu uso](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3305.txt).

Justamente por não entender estas distinções as pessoas acham estranho XML ter URIs (e na verdade elas acham que possuem URLs). Perdi a conta de quantos programadores reclamam que não gostariam que o arquivo precisasse acessar a internet por que tem um endereço *web* dentro dele. O que tem ali no [*namespace* XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) é um URI. Ou seja, é apenas um identificador e que por acaso também é um endereço *web*, mas é só uma forma única para identificar como é formado aquele *namespace*. Ele serve como referência, mas o acesso à internet só será necessário se um humano quiser saber mais sobre aquilo, nenhuma aplicação acessa a internet por causa daquilo a não ser que o programador deseje.

## Mais referências

Mais informações podem ser lidas no [artigo em inglês da Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_identifier). Os *links* ali, especialmente para outros artigos da própria Wikipedia, são bem interessantes e podem completar uma informação que não parece em um primeiro momento mas é valiosa.

Antes de supor alguma coisa é melhor entender bem o significado de cada coisa em todos seus detalhes.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Esse "***na Internet***" do trecho "*URI [...] é uma cadeia de caracteres compacta usada para identificar ou denominar um recurso na Internet*" da Wikipedia, está incorreto né, e não tem também na versão em inglês. Lá eles dizem apenas que é usado em redes, geralmente a World Wide Web. Eu sei que você citou o que estava lá, mas de repente era bom colocar um aviso para deixar claro!

Comment: @PedroGaspar na pt está exatamente assim, na en é um pouco ambíguo ou incompleto.

Comment: Tentei corrigir "Você tem o **procolo** `mailto:` ..." para  "Você tem o **protocolo** `mailto:` ..." mas o Stack Overflow impediu a edição exibindo a seguinte mensagem: "**As edições devem ter no mínimo 6 caracteres. Há mais alguma coisa para melhorar esta publicação?**"