# Qual é a finalidade da classe Uri?

Tags: c#, .net, string, uri

O que é a classe `Uri` e qual é a sua finalidade e onde devo usar?

Não é possível passar um objeto dela para uma variável string veja no exemplo:

```
String caminho = new Uri(@"c:\Windows");
```

Gera o seguinte erro:

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Uri' to 'string'

[Li a respeito](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) que é utilizado em strings, porem estou confuso a isso.

Comment: Se não for usar as funcionalidade da classe `Uri`, não faz sentido pensar em usá-la: [rtfm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-BR/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Já respondi [o que é URI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43224/101).

No fundo é um "endereço" canônico de um recurso. E usa onde precisa de um endereço desses. Se precisa de um endereço de uma página na internet, um caminho de arquivo, uma referência que tenha um padrão de onde está e o que é aquilo.

Obviamente ele possui um formato e regras do que pode ter ali.

Não é usado em *strings*. É possível obter uma *string* gerada com o conteúdo de um URI, assim como criar uma URI tentando *parsear* uma *string*.

A sintaxe está claramente incorreta. Está criando um objeto do tipo `Uri` e tentando guardar em um tipo `String`, não dá. Nestes casos um [`var`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47383/101) costuma ser a melhor opção.

A [documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) talvez ajude alguma coisa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).