# O que são namespaces no XML?

Tags: xml, wpf, xaml, namespace, xml-namespaces

Bem, eu entendo o conceito de *namespaces* em C#, C++, etc.

Mas não entendo o conceito de *namespaces* em WPF (XAML).

Estive tentando entender os parâmetros `xmlns` em um código XAML. Li publicações MSDN sobre o assunto mas sinceramente ainda não entendi o conceito de *namespaces* em XML.

Comment: Você tem alguma dúvida específica, porque se já sabe como é no C#/C++, já sabe quase tudo o que tem que saber, basicamente tem uma sintaxe diferente. Ou seja, estou achando a pergunta uma tanto ampla.

Comment: Meu conhecimento de XML é pouquíssimo. Mas sei que os namespaces em C# e C++ por exemplo tem a finalidade de evitar conflitos de nomes.
Qual a finalidade de namespaces em XML? E pq geralmente apontam para um endereço URL?
Tembém queria entender a sintaxe `xmlns:anyLetter`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Em essência a finalidade é evitar conflito de nomes também, igual ao *namespace* do C# ou C++. A sintaxe da declaração e importação são diferentes, mas funciona de forma análoga (não idêntica). Continua sendo [apenas um sobrenome para os seus membros](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101).

A ideia veio do XML. Lá fazia um pouco mais de sentido usar [URIs](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43224/101), afinal ele é usado para troca de dados com terceiros e a chance de dois nomes do próprio *namespace* conflitarem é muito grande. Qual a forma de garantir que seu *namespace* é único? Usar um nome que você tenha controle, que ninguém mais poderá usar um igual (não que exista uma proibição, mas há um convenção, quem não a seguir quer encrenca). Um nome que você tem controle é um URI com seu domínio de internet. E ele é só isto, um nome.

Porque tem um URI muita gente acha que aquilo serve para conectar na internet e pegar algo. Nada! É só um texto descritivo, nada impede de usar outra coisa, mas aí o risco de conflito se torna maior.

Em XAML, que é usado em ambiente mais restrito, a chance é bem menor, ainda assim há um risco quando usar componentes de terceiros. De qualquer forma manteve a convenção do XML.

Muitas vezes isso é um mapeamento com o *namespace* do código C#. Exemplo:

```
clr-namesapce:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib
```

Vou deixar algumas referências que talvez não tenha lido e deve ajudar:

- [XAML Namespaces and Namespace Mapping for WPF XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/xaml-namespaces-and-namespace-mapping-for-wpf-xaml?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
- [How to: Import a Namespace into XAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/bb514546(v=vs.100)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)
- [Artigo no Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/111911/A-Guide-to-Cleaner-XAML-with-Custom-Namespaces-and)

Se tiver outras dúvidas mais específicas pode ir fazendo individualmente.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Aqui no meu projeto WPF, o código XAML tem vários namespaces.
`xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"`
`xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`
`xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"`
`xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"`
`xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Views"`

Cada um desses é um namespace? Caso sejam, não bastaria um?

Comment: Cada declaração dessa tem uma característica diferente de uso, note que há um prefixo em cada um indicando para que ele serve. Alguns são para ferramentas específicas. Neste caso não bastaria um, porque eles possuem funções diferentes. Mas não pense que está criando *namespaces* diferentes. Tem que ver o que cada um significa. É confuso mesmo :) Ex.: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350024(v=vs.110).aspx,