# Codificação POST

Tags: c#, string, post, url, webrequest

Em requisições Web ao postar dados em um servidor uma *string* do modelo abaixo (utilizando os parâmetros):

```
string hello = "hello";
string token = "teste==";
```

É transformada em dados de post iguais aos mostrados abaixo:

```
string post = "msg=hello&token=teste%3D%3D";
```

Que tipo de codificação foi utilizada aqui, sei que pode ser usada a classe JSON serializer para serializar parâmetros, mas, qual codificação foi utilizada acima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso é chamado [*percent encoding*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). É utilizado para permitir escapar caracteres que fazem parte do conteúdo mas se confundem com caracteres especiais usados em indicações específicas de [URL/URI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43224/101). Todos os caracteres básicos de texto são chamados de *unreserved characters*. O mesmo vale para codificação de dados binários já que estes fogem do texto comum (*unreserved characters*) e precisam escapar a representação de todos os 256 bytes possíveis.

A [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) descreve isso.

A codificação de caracteres depende do que foi estabelecido, é muito comum na web ser UTF-8, mas não é obrigatório, eu por exemplo evito usá-lo.

Comment: E como quase sempre, a wikipedia em português com conteúdo pela metade. Pra quem não sabe, muitas vezes é difícil colaborar com a WP em PT (eu mesmo já desisti) pq tem uns coronéis lusófonos que não entendem de nada, mas fazem questão de meter o bedelho para o nome aparecer na edição (e assim que chegaram no posto de "coronel"). Pra quem tiver a curiosidade, ou quiser melhorar o artigo, segue o link: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_por_cento (a tradução literal do título tb ficou estranha)