# Quando usar o termo "url" ou "link"?

Tags: terminologia

Esses dias comecei um "pequeno debate" aqui no TI a respeito desse assunto. Percebi que várias funções, onde retornávamos o caminho da imagem (para o navegador), estava com o nome de `getImageLink`.

Por exemplo:

```
public function getImageLink() {

      return $this->base_url . '/imagens/' . $this->id . '.jpg';
}
```

O retorno disso seria:

```
'http://meusite/imagens/1.jpg'
```

Daí eu comecei a pensar que talvez "link" se referisse à uma "url" utilizada com a tag `<a>`. Não sei se minha afirmação está correta, mas no final decidi mudar o nome dos métodos, que passaram a se chamar `getImageUrl`.

Eu peguei o costume ao ouvir as pessoas falando "link" e "url" quando se trata do endereço de um site que digitamos na barra de navegação do navegador, por exemplo.

## Perguntas

- Do ponto de vista da programação, eu deveria chamar esse "caminho da imagem" (para o navegador), de "url" ou "link"?
- O que é "link" e o que é "url"? Qual é a diferença entre um e outro?
- Para ser "link", tem que ser algo clicável?

Comment: Especificamente sobre URL: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43224/101

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O "caminho" de uma imagem, ou qualquer recurso, é sempre uma URL.

A sigla [URL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL) significa *"Localizador Uniforme de Recursos"* e descreve o padrão de nomeação do endereço de qualquer coisa que possa ser acessada numa rede.

O termo "[Hiperlink](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiperliga%C3%A7%C3%A3o)" é derivado do conceito de [Hipertexto](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hipertexto) e fortemente associado à [Web](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web).

Por conta da onipresença da Web, os 2 termos se tornaram quase intercambiáveis já que todo link vai apontar para uma URL, e quase toda URL que você acessa vem de um link. Informalmente não vai haver distinção ou problema em se usar os 2 termos à vontade.

No caso de uma função como a do seu exemplo, o que está sendo retornado é uma URL, não um hiperlink. Esse vai ser o caso para a maioria das funções desse tipo, a não ser que elas existam para montar um hiperlink dentro de uma página de hipertexto.

Acho difícil que qualquer pessoa lendo seu código vá se confundir se você usar `getImageLink` ao invés de `getImageURL`, mas o correto nesse caso seria `getImageURL`.