# XSD.EXE Gerar classes no C# - EFD Reinf v1_04_00

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, web-service

Estou tentando gerar pelo XSD.exe as classes em C# a partir dos arquivos XSD da Reinf:

> **EFD Reinf v1_04_00**
>   http://sped.rfb.gov.br/arquivo/show/2802

Da seguinte forma:

```
C:\Reinf\XSD>xsd evtInfoContribuinte-v1_04_00.xsd /classes
```

o XSD.exe retorna erro:

```
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.6.1055.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature' el
ement is not declared. Line 754, position 10.

Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce
 incorrect results.

Error: Error generating classes for schema 'evtInfoContribuinte-v1_04_00'.
  - The element 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature' is missing.

If you would like more help, please type "xsd /?".

C:\Reinf\XSD>xsd evtInfoContribuinte-v1_04_00.xsd /classes
Microsoft (R) Xml Schemas/DataTypes support utility
[Microsoft (R) .NET Framework, Version 4.6.1055.0]
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Schema validation warning: The 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature' el
ement is not declared. Line 754, position 10.

Warning: Schema could not be validated. Class generation may fail or may produce
 incorrect results.

Error: Error generating classes for schema 'evtInfoContribuinte-v1_04_00'.
  - The element 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#:Signature' is missing.
```

Entendi que no XSD ele está dando erro aqui:

```
<xs:element ref="ds:Signature"/>
```

Removi esta linha e deu certo.

Minha dúvida: Seria esse o procedimento correto (remover)?
Uma vez que é o arquivo XSD disponibilizado pela Receita Federal.

As classes geradas não ficariam incompletas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você poderia baixar o arquivo `xmldsig-core-schema.xsd` (você pode consegui-lo, por exemplo, baixando o [Pacote de Comunicação do eSocial v1.5](https://portal.esocial.gov.br/manuais/pacote-de-comunicacao-esocial-v1-5.zip), na pasta `\XSD\Eventos\RetornoEvento`) e executar o comando dessa forma:

```
xsd.exe /classes evtInfoContribuinte-v1_04_00.xsd xmldsig-core-schema.xsd
```

Dessa forma não daria o erro, e a classe resultante seria criada com todos os componentes do elemento `Signature`.

Mas, eliminando a linha que faz referência ao `ds:Signature`, como você fez, não traz nenhum efeito colateral e na verdade é até melhor porque deixará a classe gerada menos poluída, e, na prática, esse elemento `Signature` nunca será usado no objeto, já que a assinatura deve ser gerada a partir do XML completo e já serializado.

Os arquivos XSD normalmente são mais usados para a validação dos arquivos XML, e, em se tratando de validação, esse elemento `Signature` é essencial, ele deve existir no XML final. Mas para criar as classes, que serão usadas depois para serialização, o `Signature` não faz falta porque nunca será usado.

Aproveitando, a forma como eu uso o comando `xsd.exe` é assim (quebrei em diversas linhas para ficar mais legível, mas é um comando só):

```sh
xsd /c /f /l:cs
    /u:http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/evtInfoContribuinte/v1_04_00
    /n:R1000
    evtInfoContribuinte-v1_04_00.xsd
```

- `/c` é um apelido para `/classes`;
- `/f` indica que serão criados campos (*fields*) ao invés de propriedades (*properties*);
- `/l:cs` indica que a linguagem de saída será C#, mas esse já é o padrão;
- `/u:[uri]` indica o [URI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43224/86952) do *namespace* do XSD que você está importando (lembrando que no caso do Reinf, cada evento terá um URI diferente);
- `/n:[namespace]` indica o seu namespace na aplicação alvo.

---

**EDIÇÃO**

**Dica:** Coloque cada *schema* convertido em um namespace específico, porque todos eles têm o elemento raiz com o mesmo nome, `Reinf`, e quando você adicionar a classe do segundo *schema* já dará conflito, se não estiverem em namespaces separados. Você pode colocar essa primeira classe (extraída do *schema* `evtInfoContribuinte-v1_04_00.xsd`) no namespace `R1000`, usando a opção `/n:R1000` na linha de comando, por exemplo:

```
namespace R1000 {
    using System.Xml.Serialization;

    public partial class Reinf {
        public ReinfEvtInfoContri evtInfoContri;
    }

    // [...]
}
```

Se converter o *schema* de comunicação `retornoLoteEventos-v1_04_00.xsd`, pode coloca-lo no namespace `RetornoLoteEventos`, usando a opção `/n:RetornoLoteEventos` na linha de comando, e assim por diante.

Comment: Gerando a  retornoLoteEventos-v1_04_00.cs a partir do XSD, 
Ele gera na classe gerada varias referências duplicadas a esses atributos:
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.6.1055.0")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true, Namespace="http://www.reinf.esocial.gov.br/schemas/retornoLoteEventos/v1_04_00")]
....   Que resulta em erros de compilação É normal isso ?  Gerar essas duplicidades?

Comment: Outra dúvida: na hora de gerar a classe pelo XSD.EXE vocês estão definindo um namespace especifico para cada XSD? Pergunto porque alguns nomes de propriedades já estão dando conflito de nomes iguais....                                                   Ex:  O tipo "TStatus" já contém uma definição para "descRetorno", onde ele tem a mesma definição em retornoLoteEventos-v1_04_00.cs  e  retornoTotalizadorEvento-v1_04_00.cs

Comment: Sim, é normal a ferramenta criar todos esses atributos, mas provavelmente não é isso que está dando erro de duplicação (e isso já responderá seu outro comentário), o que provavelmente está dando erro de duplicação é que o elemento raiz de todos os schemas é o `Reinf`, então no segundo esquema que você converter já dará duplicação, e, sim, usamos namespaces diferentes, veja a dica que te dei no item 2 dessa outra resposta: [EFD Reinf v1_04_00 - Como instanciar e preencher todas propriedades dos Eventos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/348662/86952)

Comment: Editei a minha resposta aqui para incluir essa informação.

Comment: Sim, ficou bem claro e o erro corrigido...

Comment: Que bom, espero que um dia essa resposta seja [útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) para alguém! ;-)